# Какая структура папок должна быть?

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Имеется такой вот сайт - ufc.ru, а так же у него имеется несколько поддоменов: api.ufc.ru, chat.ufc.ru данный сайт на паттерне MVC. Мой вопрос такой, как правильно создать структуру папок для поддоменых сайтов? Моя структура на данный момент такая:

```
-app
--controllers
---// тут у меня файлы
--views
---//тут тоже
--models
---//тоже
```

Будет ли правильно создать 2 папки api, chat в папках controllers, views, models? Как правильно создать структуру папок?

Comment: Такие вещи обычно раскидывают по микросервисам

Comment: Если эти сайты предполагаются быть полностью отдельными, то тогда не имеет никакого значения, в каких папках они располагаются. Ну а так как каждый отдельный сайт может (и, вероятно, должен) быть на своём отдельном сервере — рассуждать о структуре папок вообще не имеет смысла

Comment: То есть, мне нужно покупать 3 хостинга и 3 домена и к ним привязывать свой айпишник?

Comment: Ну а если у меня вот допустим основной домен ufc.ru, а так же вот такой *.ufc.ru то есть, будет логин пользователя, как мне тогда это сделать?

Comment: Если у вас нет лишних денег — можете и одним хостингом обойтись. Но если сайты предполагаются быть отдельными, значит каждый отдельный сайт просто будет одной-единственной папкой (только вместо «app» наверное логичнее использовать какое-то осмысленное имя) со своими controllers/views/models, а в каких родительских папках эти сайты будут находиться и как будут расположены относительно друг друга — уже не имеет никакого значения

Comment: По сути вопрос имеет смысл только если все домены будут страницами одного большого сайта, и нужно как-то определиться, как в этом одном сайте структурировать файлы. Если вы используете какой-то готовый php-фреймворк, то, наверное, стоит посмотреть его документацию — наверняка в ней есть какие-то рекомендации на этот счёт. Если нет, то есть такая базовая рекомендация — каждая задача в отдельной папке (например, корзина в папке cart, видео в папке video, новости в папке news, чат в папке chat и т. п.) — а дальше уже сами думайте, какое деление лучше всего подходит для вашего конкретного сайта

Comment: А ну и да, обычно создают не api, chat внутри controllers, views, models, а наоборот — папки controllers, views, models создают внутри папок api, chat

Comment: Понял! Спасибо большое